# Applescript timed out in iTunes

Tags: applescript, itunes

I wrote a simple applescript to automatically add files into iTunes and fill the metadata. When I run it directly from the editor it works but running it from iTunes and I will get "AppleEvent Timed Out".

Here's the code:

```
set mainFolder to choose folder

tell application "Finder"
    -- Loop through all shows
    set shows to every folder of mainFolder
    repeat with show from 1 to count of shows

        -- Set Show Name
        set showName to name of item show of shows

        -- Set Artist
        display dialog "Who is the artist for " & showName & "?" default answer showName
        set showArtist to the text returned of the result

        -- Set Genre
        display dialog "What is the genre for " & showName & "?" default answer ""
        set showGenre to the text returned of the result

        -- Loop through all season
        set seasons to every folder in item show of shows
        repeat with season from 1 to count of seasons

            set seasonName to name of item season of seasons

            -- Set Season Number
            set seasonNumber to text 1 thru ((offset of "-" in seasonName) - 2) of seasonName as integer

            -- Set Year
            display dialog "What year was Season " & seasonNumber & " of " & showName & " in?" default answer "2012"
            set showYear to the text returned of the result

            -- Set Season Name      
            set seasonName to text ((offset of "-" in seasonName) + 2) thru ((offset of "." in seasonName) - 1) of seasonName as text

            -- Set Total Episodes in Season
            set totalEpisodes to count of every file in item season of seasons

            -- Loop through all episodes
            set episodes to every file in item season of seasons
            repeat with episode from 1 to count of episodes

                set episodeName to name of item episode of episodes

                -- Set Episode Number
                set episodeNumber to text 1 thru ((offset of "-" in episodeName) - 2) of episodeName as integer

                -- Set Episode Name
                set episodeName to text ((offset of "-" in episodeName) + 2) thru ((offset of "." in episodeName) - 1) of episodeName as text

                tell application "iTunes"
                    set newAddition to (add (item episode of episodes as alias))
                    tell newAddition
                        set video kind to TV show
                        set name to episodeName
                        set album to seasonName
                        set track number to episodeNumber
                        set track count to totalEpisodes
                        set disc number to "1"
                        set disc count to "1"
                        set show to showName
                        set season number to seasonNumber
                        set episode number to episodeNumber

                        -- Manual Entries
                        set artist to showArtist
                        set genre to showGenre
                        set year to showYear


                        -- Change episode ID based on season and episode number
                        if (seasonNumber < 10) then
                            if (episodeNumber < 10) then
                                set episode ID to ("S0" & seasonNumber as text) & "E0" & episodeNumber as text
                            else
                                set episode ID to ("S0" & seasonNumber as text) & "E" & episodeNumber as text
                            end if
                        else
                            if (episodeNumber < 10) then
                                set episode ID to ("S" & seasonNumber as text) & "E0" & episodeNumber as text
                            else
                                set episode ID to ("S" & seasonNumber as text) & "E" & episodeNumber as text
                            end if
                        end if

                    end tell -- End newAddition
                end tell -- End iTunes
            end repeat -- End Episode Repeat
        end repeat -- End Season Repeat
    end repeat -- End Show Repeat
end tell -- End Finder Repeat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved it:

Save as an app instead of a script.

I got the solution from here: 
http://forums.ilounge.com/applescripts-itunes-mac/245120-need-help-add-tracks-files-via-applescript.html

I have no clue why it's doing that, I've tried using try-catch, timeout... still didn't work. It works as an app though?!

Answer (score 0):

the code itself seems sound assuming you don't have any errors when calculating the offsets and different components of the file name. However I can see 2 possible sources of errors that may fix your problem.

First, you have your iTunes tell block of code inside your Finder tell block of code. Essentially you are telling the Finder to tell iTunes to do something. That is a source of possible errors. You should separate your tell blocks from each other. For example you have this...

```
tell application "Finder"
    -- do something
    tell application "iTunes"
        -- do something
    end tell
end tell
```

When you should have it like this...

```
tell application "Finder"
    -- do something
end tell

tell application "iTunes"
    -- do something
end tell
```

Second, you have a mistake in your "episode id" code with the parenthesis. For example this...

```
("S0" & seasonNumber as text)
```

Should be this...

```
"S0" & (seasonNumber as text)
```

As such I have separated out the iTunes stuff into a subroutine and fixed the parenthesis. Note that I haven't tested this code. I think I passed all of the proper variables to the subroutine but I can't be certain. I hope this helps.

```
set mainFolder to choose folder

tell application "Finder"
    -- Loop through all shows
    set shows to every folder of mainFolder
    repeat with show from 1 to count of shows

        -- Set Show Name
        set showName to name of item show of shows

        -- Set Artist
        display dialog "Who is the artist for " & showName & "?" default answer showName
        set showArtist to the text returned of the result

        -- Set Genre
        display dialog "What is the genre for " & showName & "?" default answer ""
        set showGenre to the text returned of the result

        -- Loop through all season
        set seasons to every folder in item show of shows
        repeat with season from 1 to count of seasons

            set seasonName to name of item season of seasons

            -- Set Season Number
            set seasonNumber to text 1 thru ((offset of "-" in seasonName) - 2) of seasonName as integer

            -- Set Year
            display dialog "What year was Season " & seasonNumber & " of " & showName & " in?" default answer "2012"
            set showYear to the text returned of the result

            -- Set Season Name      
            set seasonName to text ((offset of "-" in seasonName) + 2) thru ((offset of "." in seasonName) - 1) of seasonName as text

            -- Set Total Episodes in Season
            set totalEpisodes to count of every file in item season of seasons

            -- Loop through all episodes
            set episodes to every file in item season of seasons
            repeat with episode from 1 to count of episodes

                set episodeName to name of item episode of episodes

                -- Set Episode Number
                set episodeNumber to text 1 thru ((offset of "-" in episodeName) - 2) of episodeName as integer

                -- Set Episode Name
                set episodeName to text ((offset of "-" in episodeName) + 2) thru ((offset of "." in episodeName) - 1) of episodeName as text

                my addEpisodeToItunes((item episode of episodes) as alias, seasonName, seasonNumber, episodeName, episodeNumber, totalEpisodes, showName, showArtist, showGenre, showYear)
            end repeat -- End Episode Repeat
        end repeat -- End Season Repeat
    end repeat -- End Show Repeat
end tell -- End Finder Repeat

on addEpisodeToItunes(theEpisode, seasonName, seasonNumber, episodeName, episodeNumber, totalEpisodes, showName, showArtist, showGenre, showYear)
    tell application "iTunes"
        set newAddition to add theEpisode
        tell newAddition
            set video kind to TV show
            set name to episodeName
            set album to seasonName
            set track number to episodeNumber
            set track count to totalEpisodes
            set disc number to "1"
            set disc count to "1"
            set show to showName
            set season number to seasonNumber
            set episode number to episodeNumber

            -- Manual Entries
            set artist to showArtist
            set genre to showGenre
            set year to showYear


            -- Change episode ID based on season and episode number
            if (seasonNumber < 10) then
                if (episodeNumber < 10) then
                    set episode ID to "S0" & (seasonNumber as text) & "E0" & (episodeNumber as text)
                else
                    set episode ID to "S0" & (seasonNumber as text) & "E" & (episodeNumber as text)
                end if
            else
                if (episodeNumber < 10) then
                    set episode ID to "S" & (seasonNumber as text) & "E0" & (episodeNumber as text)
                else
                    set episode ID to "S" & (seasonNumber as text) & "E" & (episodeNumber as text)
                end if
            end if

        end tell -- End newAddition
    end tell -- End iTunes
end addEpisodeToItunes
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I tried your code and you pointed out some good errors. Unfortunately, your script suffers from the same problem that mine did. If I run it directly from the editor it works fine, if I run it from iTunes, it says "AppleEvent Timed It".